# Is it possible to call AWS Step Function from Mulesoft?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, mulesoft

I am new to both platform. Is it possible if I will invoke AWS Step function from Mulesoft?

Answer (score 1):

I see no reason why not. However there is no existing connector for AWS step APIhttps://www.mulesoft.com/exchange/?search=Aws). This means that you will need to write either your own connector or write all the API REST calls by yourself.

Comment: Can you give some illustration how to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: The most basic way is to just use HTTP requests in your application against the AWS API. See the documentation of the HTTP Requester connector https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/http/http-request-ref and the AWS documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/Welcome.html